# What is the correct way of loading some data from database in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, async-await, provider, fetching-strategy

Considering we have a function like following that loads up data from database:

```
  loadData() async {
    loadedData = await loadingData();
    return loadedData;
  }
```

And we want to use this `loadedData` inside the same or other class/widget using `Provider` package.

I tried many ways like putting `loadData()` inside `initState()` or `didChangeDependencies()` like following:

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    data = await Provider.of<>(context , listen: false).loadData();
  }
```

Or using `Consumer` or trying to pass data using `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider` at the startup of the application but still have problems most of the time and getting errors like `null` value errors or some other related errors(Can't remember at the moment).

***I like to know what is the correct way of fetching data from database and wait for data in a `Widget`?***

For example I know if I change `(listen: false)` to `(listen: true)` within the `Provider` command I can read data but it seems it updates the app very much and I can hear the rising noise of the CPU fan that I don't like it!

Please give me a simple code example/snippet to understand the correct way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FutureBuilder` to load data like this:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Provider.of<MyData>(context, listen: false).loadData(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<MyData> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(
            child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
          );
        } else {
          MyData data = snapshot.data!;
          // Use the loaded data to build your widget
          return Text(data.someProperty);
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of loadData using the provider. If you don't want to eager load the data, just remove initState() method.

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
    void initState() {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        context.read<TestModel>().loadData();
      });
      super.initState();
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _buildContent()
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContent() {
    ///context.watch only rebuild when [TestModel] changes.
    TestModel testModel = context.watch<TestModel>();
    if (testModel.isLoading) {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      } else {
        return Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(testModel.data),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async => await testModel.loadData(),
                child: Text('Click to Load Data'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }

class TestModel with ChangeNotifier {
  String _data = '';
  bool _isLoading = false;

  String get data => _data;
  bool get isLoading => _isLoading;

  Future<void> loadData() async {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    // your logic here
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    _data = 'Finish loading data with result';
    _isLoading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FutureBuilder or via using turnery operators.

```
data == null || data.isEmpty
? CircularProgressIndicator() 
: Center(
    child: Text("It is working")
),
```